# Transcoding custom file type to mpeg-4

Tags: metadata, h.264, mpeg-4, ms-media-foundation

I have a custom video file which consists of a custom header followed by UYVY type YUV format.  The header tags contain special information regarding the location of the picture, so I need to preserve them.

I am currently converting the UYVY to YUY2 in order to use Microsoft Media Foundation H.264 encoder to create mpeg-4 files, however I can not figure out how to preserve the metadata.

My question is how do I preserve the custom metadata into newly encoded mp4 file using the Microsoft Media Foundation?  The IPropertyStore talks about using a custom XML file to describe how to handle the custom metadata, but I can't find any examples of how to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: What metadata is it? Are you talking about the transparency per picture ? or is it more like Author and album like data? Does it vary per picture? (is it meant to be for everypicture?) or is this for the whole video?

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to `32 bit ARGB` with Alpha plane with transparency preserved, i am afraid - this cannot be done by any conventional MPEG coded.

Your best bet is, to use MPEG 4 "Object video" - understand, this is not normal MPEG4 or DivX, but - this is object video. There is a reasonable work involved in this.

Look at [MoMuSys codec](http://cordis.europa.eu/infowin/acts/analysys/products/thematic/mpeg4/momusys/momusys.htm) and [this](http://www.img.lx.it.pt/~fp/Klagenfurt/Study%20Material/MPEG4_overview_1.pdf) link for more details.

Refine your question if this is not what you intended.

EDIT: 
Only for the purpose of Metadata if it is similar to ID3 tags in MP3, there is a mechanism available in MP4 file format.

This link : http://www.semanticmetadata.net/2008/03/07/metadata-for-the-mp4-container/ shows some tools that might help.

Alternativly - XMP (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform) is also said to be usable under MP4 fileformat.

MP4 file format can very well handle H.264 encoding.

Comment: I took your suggestion about using mpeg 4, and also edited the question to make it more clear.  The question is really how to preserve metadata when using the h.264 encoder.  Thanks for your help.